# Failing to ssh only from windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssh, mac, putty

I am trying to ssh (to a Nvidia Xavier but that is not relevant) and when I do it from my mac I got no problem, I can access the other machine.
However when I try to do it from windows 10 (using Putty, SuperPutty and even the comand line) I cannot access the other machine

The connection times out, etc.

I suspect it has to deal with some security protection against connecting to other equipment but I am not sure

Can anybody share some pointers on what I should do?

Comment: Have you tried the optional OpenSSH client?  How about WSL2 it really sounds like a firewall or security software configuration issue

Comment: In a galaxy long long ago, I used to telnet to the target to port 22 and observe the ssh banner. But these days people rarely install the tenet client on win10.   personally I'd suspect a fire wall issue ruining connectivity.  That's one thing telnet was good for exercising.

Comment: if no telnet, try curl: `curl -v telnet://IP:22` (replace IP of course)